# Match a word before a delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a string like this: `[this] is amazing - for [real]`, I want to match all `[` or `]` but only that is before the `-`;

How can I do that with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[\[\]](?=.*-)
```

This matches any square brackets as long as it is followed by some sequence that contains a `-`

See a demo here

https://regex101.com/r/GLapGl/3